# Livetrabscription from browser tab

Tags: javascript, python, node.js, microsoft-teams

I have a plan to make a browser extension for chrome that's make a live transcription of my teams meeting from opened tab in browser. I want to take a transcripted speech and find in this text key word like my name. I am from Poland from this reason I can't use live transcription built in teams to because this transcript to English

This be similar to this app

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.audio.hearing.visualization.accessibility.scribe&hl=pl&gl=US

But I have a problem I can find an information how to get access to audio from a browser tab. Those anyone knows how API or have idea how to get this information ?

Comment: Hi @pawel szewczyk,

To enable transcription for a user's meeting, the Teams meeting policy you are assigned to must have the -AllowTranscription setting set to true.

Could you please go through the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/cloud-recording).

Comment: @pawel szewczyk, Please let us know does that help clarify.

Comment: Not much but I find that api on microsoft page :P https://learn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/azure/cognitive-services/speech-service/how-to-use-conversation-transcription?pivots=programming-language-javascript

Answer (score 0):

Posting the Answer for better knowledge
Copying from @pawel szewczyk comments.

To get real-time Conversation Transcription use Azure Conversation Transcription Signature REST APIs. Please follow this [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/speech-service/how-to-use-conversation-transcription?pivots=programming-language-javascript).